# kartik datepicker not working in yii2

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have used kartik datepicker in yii2 advance application, It was working before I using custom css, not getting any error only input field showing.
View Code:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use \app\models\Company;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use kartik\datecontrol\Module;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;
use \app\models\Project;
use \app\models\Doctype;
use \app\models\Status;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Project */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="project-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <!--DropdownList created here-->
    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_comp_id')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(), 'comp_id', 'comp_name'),
        [
            'prompt' => 'Select Project',
        ]);
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'project_desc')->textArea(['rows' => '6']) ?>
    <?=  $form-> field($model, 'project_start_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Start date & time'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                    ]
                ]);
    ?>  
     <?=  $form-> field($model, 'project_end_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'End date & time'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                    ]
                ]);
        ?>

<!-- 
    <?= $form->field($model, 'created')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'verified')->dropDownList([ 'Y' => 'Y', 'N' => 'N', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'updated')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'deleted')->dropDownList([ 'Y' => 'Y', 'N' => 'N', ], ['prompt' => '']) ?>
 -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

In the following image form structure is showing:
[image]

Comment: Try adding: `use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;` and `use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;`

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Class 'kartik\widgets\DatePicker' not found getting this error

Comment: $ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widgets "*"

Comment: https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widgets

Comment: Most probably you don't have download the kartik widgets. Add them using composer and it should be ok.

Comment: tried both things still not resolved the issue.

Comment: Hm, try to see if jQuery is working.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple solution

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;

echo '<label>Check Issue Date</label>';
echo DatePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'check_issue_date', 
    'value' => date('d-M-Y', strtotime('+2 days')),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
        'todayHighlight' => true
    ]
]);
```

Add this to the require section of your composer.json file:

```
"kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev"
```

[image]